# I can't find where this margin is coming from using Mozilla's Dev Tools

Tags: html, css, margin

If you take a look at the HTML, I've pointed out the element H1.
If you look at the Box Model on the bottom right, it shows a margin of 15.936 on the top and bottom (0 on left and right). I can't find it at all in my code.

Is it something with the `box-sizing: content-box`? Or `display: block`?

[image: Mozilla Dev Tools]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heading tags by default have a top and bottom margin. I believe it is `0.67em`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that! How do we get rid of that margin?
Should I just use box-sizing on the entire page?

Comment: You can just override it with `margin: 0`